# Como abrir um arquivo PDF nos itens da listView?

Tags: android, pdf, arraylist

Criei uma lista ArrayList e queria abrir arquivos pdf nela, mas eu estou armazenando os arquivos pdf na pasta res/raw e ao chamar na String ("res/raw") o arquivo simplesmente não abre, o que eu faço?

Comment: Minha sugestão é usar alguma biblioteca com boa reputação para renderizar o PDF, tem uma lista disponível no android arsenal: https://android-arsenal.com/tag/72?sort=rating com varias opções.

Comment: Sim, mas como adicionar o pdf em Array?

Comment: O ideal é vocẽ acessar o InputStream, usando o `context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.nome_do_pdf)`. Você quer abrir todos os PDFs do ArraysList ao mesmo tempo ou apenas um de cada vez? Recomendo olhar na documentação da biblioteca, como ela espera que você passe o PDF para ela renderizar, porque pode variar muito.

Comment: Quero abrir um pdf diferente para cada clique do Array, o problema é que quando eu clico no item da lista, o pedf não aparece, ele simplesmente aparece uma tela branca.

Comment: Olha eu coloquei assim pra acessar:PDFView novo = (PDFView) findViewById(pdfView);
        novo.fromAsset("texto.pdf").load();

Comment: Mas mostra uma tela em branco e no log aparece a seguinte mensagem:05-19 16:47:44.637 23878-23878/com.example.android.contos V/ActivityThread: updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{4ca7407 token=android.os.BinderProxy@c905bfe {com.example.android.contos/com.example.android.contos.MainActivity}} show : false

Comment: Esse erro não ajuda muito, seria bom dizer qual lib está usando, e não deveria passar o id do resource em vez de uma String?

Comment: Consegui Wakim, sabe o que que era, eu estava colocando na pasta raw, foi só mudar o arquivo pdf para a pasta assets e colocá-lá dentro da pasta main, que funcionou, vai entender!

Comment: Bacana, achei que dentro de raw também funcionaria :( Poderia incluir uma resposta com esse ajuste.